# Why does the chat show by default 32 avatars?

Tags: feature-request, chat

The chat's sidebar shows, between other informations, a list of avatars of the people currently in the room, ordered by recency of speaking.

This list consists of several rows with space for a number of icons each (which is dependent on screen width). In chatrooms with lots of people in them, this list is clipped at **32** icons ..., which is three full rows and then two more icons at a full screen window here. Then there is the link *show 3 more* (number varies) which will show the avatars of all of the members.

While 32 is a nice power of two, I think a multiple of the number of icons which fit in a row would be a quite better default number, since then we would have a full rows, instead of the last row having only two icons (which then by clicking the link changes to five icons).

I think three rows could be a quite good first approximation (at least, on my screen).

(Edited after seeing it depends on screen/window width.)

Comment: Well, the number of icons displayed per row is dependent on your screen width. The fact that it's making the decision based on a set number of icons instead of "How many icons will fit in `x` rows?" seems like it could be improved, though.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that it is screen width dependent. Seems I always measured with the same screen and full-width browser.

Comment: @Tim: I edited the question (and made it a feature-request).

Comment: @Tim You could clip the user list at the CSS level... although then I'm not sure how easy it would be to determine if there are hidden contacts to show or hide for the expand/collapse link.